# How to understand the functional programming code for converting IP string to an integer?

Tags: python, functional-programming, ip

In a python discusion, I saw a function to convert IP string into an integer in functional progamming way. Here is [the Link](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/282977/ip-number-conversion-between-dotnumber-string-and-integer) .

The function is implemented in a single line.

```
def ipnumber(ip):
    return reduce(lambda sum, chunk: sum <<8 | chunk, map(int, ip.split(".")))
```

However, I have few ideas of funcional programming. Could anybody explain the function in detail? I've some knowledge of "map" and "reduce". But I don't konw what "|" and "chunk" mean here.

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, python includes this kind of batteries: `struct.unpack('!I', socket.inet_aton(ip))[0]`

Comment: I wonder what the performance difference is?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`sum` and `chunk` are arguments to the `lambda` function passed to `reduce`. `|` is the binary or operator.

The thing works like this:

- `ip.split(".")` returns a list of strings, each corresponding to a piece of the dotted string (`"192.168.0.1"` => `["192", "168", "0", "1"]`;
- `map` applies its first operand to each element of its second operand (`["192", "168", "0", "1"]` => `[192, 168, 0, 1]`);
- `reduce` takes the first two arguments from the list and applies the `lambda` to them; then it does this again with the result of the lambda and the next element of the list; and so on.
- the `labmda` function (an anonymous function defined on the spot) does this: takes the first argument, shifts it by eight bits and ORs to it the new chunk; thus, what happens is that the result is computed like:

  ```
  (((192<<8 | 168) << 8 | 0)<<8 | 1) = 192<<24 | 168<<16 | 0<<8 | 1
  ```

  which is exactly what the "dotted form" represents (it's just a shorthand to indicate a 32 bit unsigned integer, which is what an IP is in IPv4 - you could say it's a bit like expressing it in base 256)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have understood the code. I just wonder how to inplement a function to convert an Integer to IP string in this way?

Answer (score 5):

`|` is a [bitwise, logical or](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations):

```
>>> 0 | 1
1
>>> 1 | 1
1
```

Reduce calls the `lambda` with the current running total and the next (integer) value of the output of the `map()` function. So, it is doing the following in a loop:

```
sum = 0
for chunk in map(int, ip.split(".")):
    sum = (sum << 8) | chunk
```

where `map(int, ip.split("."))` turned the IP address into a sequence of integers; `1.2.3.4` becomes `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

The `<<` is a [bitwise left shift](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations), by 8 bits in this case:

```
>>> 1 << 8
256
```

So, for each integer part of an ip address, it shifts the value to the left by 8 positions, and adds the bits of the next part of the address to that number.

This makes perfect sense, since an IP address is nothing but a 32-bit number, and the string notation divides that number up into 4 chunks of 8 bits, and 'prints' the integer value of each of those 8 bits with a `.` character in between.

It helps to print each stage as a binary number:

```
>>> map(int, '1.2.3.4'.split('.'))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> bin(1)
'0b1'
>>> bin(2)
'0b10'
>>> bin(3)
'0b11'
>>> bin(4)
'0b100'
>>> bin(1 << 8)
'0b100000000'
>>> bin(1 << 8 | 2)
'0b100000010'
>>> bin((1 << 8 | 2) << 8)
'0b10000001000000000'
>>> bin((1 << 8 | 2) << 8 | 3)
'0b10000001000000011'
>>> bin(((1 << 8 | 2) << 8 | 3) << 8)
'0b1000000100000001100000000'
>>> bin(((1 << 8 | 2) << 8 | 3) << 8 | 4)
'0b1000000100000001100000100'
```